# Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling

Tags: java, rmi

I have `provider` and `consumer` are on different and always provider throwing the below error. 
Can you please let me know the reason ASAP if possible.

class loader disabled)]

```
2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)

2014-05-05 14:43:42,439 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-6000 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-26364202))     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
```

Comment: Could you include the code that produces this error?

Comment: Sorry I could not copy, as it contains more number of characters..let me check